# Export an angular element as module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created a widget using Angular element successfully, which is working fine in HTML.

But how do I export it as a module so that it can be used in another Angular, React, Vue web applications as well to import `import { acmaModule } from package-name` instead `const acmaModule = require('widge.js')`

Angular

```
export class AppModule {
  initWidget(options: any){
    console.log('options received', options)
  }

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    // Expose Window function
    (<any>window).acmeWidget = { initWidget: this.initWidget  };

     // Survey Widget
    const surveyComp: any = createCustomElement(SurveyComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('acme-survey', surveyComp);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
....
<script src="../survey-widget.js">
<script>
 acmeWidget.initWidget({
  test: "Hello world"
 })
</script>
....
</html>
```

Comment: I would go for generating a web component if I were you :)
https://blog.kalvad.com/export-your-angular-component-as-a-web-component/

Answer (score 1):

You can create an export file and declare the exporting for all modules you want to package for external references in there.

For example, you can add a file `export.ts` to the `src` folder and then add something like this to the content of the file, assuming your `AppModule` is under `src\AppModule.ts`:

```
//content of export.ts
export * from './AppModule';
...
```

then in your `ng-package.json` file, you need to declare `export.ts` as entry file there. Something like:

```json
//content of ng-package.json
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/<your built package name>",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/export.ts"
  }
}
```

then after you build your project, you can run `npm publish` to create the artifact that you can install through npm and import later. Assuming your project's name is `test-project`, it will be something like:

```bash
ng build test-project --prod

# after build is done:
cd dist/test-project
npm publish
```

see references for [npm publish](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-publish)

Comment: I will test this and update you

Comment: By using the ng-packager, that will generate an angular library, and that one cannot be used directly in react/vue, for this one you could use webpack 5 module federation feature.